# Runtime error while using stack or atoi()

Tags: c, stack, runtime-error

`#define MAXL 256`

First pass: `in = "25 7 * 14 - 6 +";` run smoothly with correct answer.

Second pass: `in = "1 24 3 + * 41 -";` program stopped right after outputting `Num got in: 41` Expected: continue loop and get in the minus sign then `pop(s)` and subtract `41`

I'm guessing that my program ran out of allocated space because of the `free()` didn't do their job as I expected but I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
double evaluatePost(char * in)
{
    double * op1 = NULL, * op2 = NULL, * msgr = NULL;
    int i, j;
    char * c = {0}, tempExp[MAXL] = {0}; 
    char ** token = NULL;
    Stack * s = createStack();

    strcpy(tempExp, in);        /* Copy in to a temporary array so strtok will not destroy in */

    for(c = strtok(tempExp, " "); c != NULL; ++i, c = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        if(isdigit(c[0]))
        {
            printf("\nNum got in: %s\n", c); /* Crash right after this line output 41 */
            system("PAUSE");
            msgr = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)); /* I made a malloc check here, it never showed error */
            *msgr = atoi(c); /* I don't know if it crash at this line or the next one */
            push(s, msgr);  /* stack has no limit, receives stack* and void* */
            /* It never got pass to here after output 41 */
        }
        else
        {
            op2 = (double *)pop(s);
            op1 = (double *)pop(s);
            printf("\n%f %f %s\n", *op1, *op2, c);
            system("PAUSE");
            msgr = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
            if(!msgr)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
                system("PAUSE");
                exit(1);
            }
            switch(*c)
            {
                case '+': *msgr = (*op1 + *op2); break;
                case '-': *msgr = (*op1 - *op2); break;
                case '*': *msgr = (*op1 * *op2); break;
                case '/': *msgr = (*op1 / *op2); break;
            }
            printf("\n%.1f\n", *msgr);
            system("PAUSE");
            /* Free the memory before they become orphans */            
            free(op1), free(op2);
            push(s, msgr);
        }       
    }   
    returnVal = *((double *)pop(s));
    makeEmpty(s);

    return returnVal;
}
void push(Stack * stack, void * dataInPtr)
{
    /* Define a new StackNode */
    StackNode * newPtr;

    /* Get some Memory */
    newPtr = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    if(!newPtr)
    {
        printf("Out of memory");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }   
    /* Assign dataIn to dataPtr */
    newPtr->dataPtr = dataInPtr;

    /* Make the links */
    newPtr->link = stack->top;  /* Point both to top */
    stack->top = newPtr;        /* newPtr at top pointed to be head */
    (stack->count)++;
}
void * pop(Stack * stack)
{
    /* Hold the data */
    void * dataOutPtr;
    StackNode * temp;

    /* Check if stack is empty */
    if(stack->count == 0)
        dataOutPtr = NULL;
    else
    {
        /* Get the data and remove the node */
        temp = stack->top;                  /* temp points to top */
        dataOutPtr = stack->top->dataPtr;   /* dataOutPtr has data */
        stack->top = stack->top->link;      /* stack moves to next node */
        temp->link = NULL;                  /* break top node off stack */
        free(temp);                         /* frees memory */
        (stack->count)--;                   
    }
    return dataOutPtr;
}
typedef struct node
{
    void * dataPtr;
    struct Node * link;
} StackNode;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    StackNode * top;
} Stack;
```

Comment: Please post `pop()` and `push()` definitions also.

Comment: Why you don't try gdb?

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild I added push, I can't make the pop code merge correctly, will keep trying.

Comment: @ARBY I don't know how to use it, this is only my 3rd exercise. I'm still very confused with everything.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild done! please help me check again, thank you!

Comment: The code doesn't compile as shown... but after fixing the obvious errors and adding missing functions, it works.  Make sure your typedefs and functions (or prototypes) appear *before* you use them (not after as shown), fix the typo in `struct node` (`struct Node`?), declare `returnVal` somewhere in `evaluatePost()`, and if that doesn't fix it show us your `createStack()` function...

Comment: @Dmitri Oh the stack and its functions are in a header file. returnVal is what I thought of when I was typing in the question, just another check. I did declare it when I tried that train of thought. I'm sorry about the wrong informations.

Comment: Any character other than a digit or operator causes you to lose the stack contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may lie here:

You are freeing the Stack node in `pop()`

```
temp = stack->top;                  /* temp points to top */
dataOutPtr = stack->top->dataPtr;   /* dataOutPtr has data */
stack->top = stack->top->link;      /* stack moves to next node */
temp->link = NULL;                  /* break top node off stack */
free(temp);                         /* frees memory */
```

And after that you are freeing the data pointer in the node in `evaluatePost()`:

```
free(op1), free(op2);
```

The sequence `free`ing the memory should always be in reverse order of `malloc` i.e. you should allocate Node first and then node data and for `free`ing `free` the node data first, and then `Node` itself.

You are facing problem with some input and not with some other input, because this is **undefined behavior**.

To know more about undefined behavior in C, you can search for related questions in SO.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with your explanation. `In reverse order of malloc`

Comment: Free the memory pointers in the opposite order as you `malloc`ed them.

Comment: But after pop, the Node is not there anymore so it's dataPtr cannot be pointing to the address that only op1 and op2 are holding of the data. Are you saying that the node that are currently pointing to null and the pointer to data still point to that address that I pass to either op1 or op2? But then why would it choose to crash not after freeing op1 or op2 but wait till later?

Comment: Maybe I'm being obtuse again, I need some rest and definitely will think about what you pointed out again tomorrow. I've been working on this project for 15 hours straight.

Comment: @MizushimaHideyoshi It's *not* required that you free items in the reverse order you allocated them... that does *not* invoke undefined behaviour.  You just need to make sure you free whatever you allocate, and only once... in *any* order (as long as the free is after the allocation, of course).

Comment: I used the same stack in another function and got 0 errors. I tried removing the `free()` in `evaluatePost()` and take a chance memory leak. It won't crash at 41. the function successfully return computed value of that `in` but as next `in` passed in, it crashes right away. My best bet is that it ran out of allocated stack space... I don't remember what's called correctly...

Comment: @Dmitri would you please suggest a better time to free them?

Comment: @MizushimaHideyoshi I didn't see anything particularly wrong with your `push()` or `pop()`... this answer is wrong about the order of the `free()`s causing undefined behaviour -- it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the ability to traverse over all the nodes in your stack without freeing them. This comes in handy, if say, after `pushing` all nodes you need to use the collection and don't want to `pop` and `free` the data, or if you need to update the nodes in some way before `popping` them. All you need to do is add a single `tail` pointer to your stack which will hold the address of the first node `pushed` onto the stack. e.g.:

```
typedef struct
{
    int count;
    StackNode *top;
    StackNode *tail;
} Stack;
```

Why? Since you have a `StackNode->link`, your data is effectively in `linked-list` form anyway. Adding a `tail` pointer that points to the first node `pushed` onto the stack, simply gives an easy way to know when to stop iterating over your `nodes`. With a few minor tweaks, you can then do what you attempted - iterate over all the nodes in your stack without having to `pop`/`free` the nodes as you do it.

Here is a short examples showing the minor tweaks needed. Also notice the cleanup removes all **casts of `malloc`** (don't do it) and a couple of cleanups on the `malloc` calls themselves:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    void *dataPtr;
    struct node *link;
} StackNode;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    StackNode *top;
    StackNode *tail;
} Stack;

Stack *stackcreate ()
{
    Stack *s = malloc (sizeof *s);
    if (!s) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s->count = 0;
    s->top = s->tail = NULL;

    return s;
}

void push(Stack * stack, void * dataInPtr)
{
    if (!stack) return;

    /* Define a new StackNode & allocate */
    StackNode *newPtr = malloc (sizeof *newPtr);
    if(!newPtr)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    /* Assign dataIn to dataPtr */
    newPtr->dataPtr = dataInPtr;
    newPtr->link = stack->top;  /* Point both to top */

    /* Make the links */
    if (!stack->top)
        stack->tail = newPtr;
    stack->top = newPtr;        /* newPtr at top pointed to be head */
    (stack->count)++;
}

void * pop(Stack * stack)
{
    /* Hold the data */
    void * dataOutPtr;
    StackNode * temp;

    /* Check if stack is empty */
    if(stack->count == 0)
        dataOutPtr = NULL;
    else
    {
        /* Get the data and remove the node */
        temp = stack->top;                  /* temp points to top */
        dataOutPtr = stack->top->dataPtr;   /* dataOutPtr has data */
        stack->top = stack->top->link;      /* stack moves to next node */
        temp->link = NULL;                  /* break top node off stack */
        free(temp);                         /* frees memory */
        (stack->count)--;
        if (!stack->top) stack->tail = NULL;
    }
    return dataOutPtr;
}

int main (void) {

    char *lines[] = { "my cat has more...",
                    "has lots of fleas, ",
                    "my dog, the lab, " };
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t entries = sizeof lines/sizeof *lines;
    Stack *stack = stackcreate ();

    for (i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        push (stack, (void *)lines[i]);

    printf (" \niterating over nodes in stack without popping\n\n");
    StackNode *p; 
    for (p = stack->top; ;p = p->link) {
        printf (" %s\n", (char *)p->dataPtr);
        if (p == stack->tail)
            break;
    }

    printf ("\n popping items from stack\n\n");
    while (stack->top) {
        printf (" %s\n", (char *)pop (stack));
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stack_iter

iterating over nodes in stack without popping

 my dog, the lab,
 has lots of fleas,
 my cat has more...

 popping items from stack

 my dog, the lab,
 has lots of fleas,
 my cat has more...
```

Comment: Even without a `tail` member, he could iterate over the nodes without popping (bottom node's `link` pointer is NULL)... but I don't see how this is relevant to OP's code (he's modifying the stack contents while evaluating an expression, not just iterating over them).

Comment: By my read, the only time the `link` pointer is `NULL` is when it is deleted. That was of little help for the iteration. You could have used `count` as well to eliminate the `tail` pointer, but the `8-bits` needed for the pointer is more than worth the readability gained in dealing with a `top` and `tail`.

Comment: If the stack's `top` pointer is `NULL` to start with, then the bottom node's `link` will be NULL.  I suppose it might not be if he leaves `top` uninitialized in `createStack()` for some reason.  Doesn't have anything to do with the error he asked about, though..

Comment: Thank you for making an example from my own code, David. I'm reading through it right now, this will definitely help. I very much appreciate it!

Comment: There is a memory leak in this answer.   at each place where a call to exit() is being performed.  any outstanding memory allocations need to be passed to free() just before calling exit().